# .js not called from html file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a video player using html and .js, however the attach1.js file cannot be called by html. Following is my html file:

```
<!Doctype html>

<html lang='en'>

        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="attach1.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="attach1.js"> </script>
        </head>

        <body>

        <section id="skin">
            <video id="myMovie" width="640" height="360">
                <source src="bnm.mp4">
            </video>

            <nav>
                <div id="buttons">
                    <button type="button" id="playButton"> Play 
                </button>
                </div>

                <div id="defaultBar">
                    <div id="progressBar"> </div>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both"> </div>
            </nav>
        </section>

        </body>

</html>
```

Following is my attach1.js:

```
        document.write('Hi');
        function doFirst()
        {
            barSize=600;
            myMovie1=document.getElementbyId('myMovie');
            playButton1=document.getElementbyId('playButton');
            bar=document.getELementbyId('defaultBar');
            progressBar1=document.getElementById('progressBar');
            document.write('Hi');
            playButton1.addEventListener('click', playorpause, false);
            bar.addEventListener('click', clicker, false);
        }

        function playorpause()
        {  
            if(!myMovie1.paused && !myMovie1.ended)
            {
                myMovie1.pause();
                playButton1.innerHTML='Play';
                window.clearInterval(updateBar);
            }

            else
            {
                myMovie1.play();
                playButton1.innerHTML='Pause';
                updateBar=setInterval(update, 500);
            }
        }

        function update()
        {
            if(!myMovie1.ended)
            {
                var size=parseInt(myMovie1.currentTime*barSize/myMovie1.duration);
                progressBar1.style.width=size+'px';
            }

            else
            {
                progressBar1.style.width='0px';
                playButton1.innerHTML='Play';
                window.clearInteval(updateBar);
            }
        }

        function clicker(e);
        {
            if(!myMovie1.paused && !myMovie1.ended)
            {
                var mouseX=e.pageX-bar.offsetLeft;
                var newtime=mouseX*myMovie1.duration/barSize;
                myMovie1.currentTime=newtime;
                progressBar1.style.width=mouseX+'px';
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', doFirst, false);
```

The attach1.js would not even print 'Hi' (in the first line of .js file). This would imply that the file is not being called by the .html file. However, I cannot figure out a reason for this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Change "document.write" to "console.log" and try this using the Firebug debugger in Firefox or the developer tools in Chrome.  Tell us what happens.

Comment: Is your javascript file attach1.js in the same folder as html document?  Filenames are case sensitive on linux machine (attach1.js!=attach1.JS).

Comment: where is your html file, where is the js file - what do you see when you load the right url for the javascript file directly in your browser? The most obvious cause is the src simply doesn't point at your js file.

Comment: Both the .html and .js are in the same folder. Checked case sensitivity as well, no issues there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got:

```
function clicker(e);
{
//code
}
```

rather than

```
function clicker(e)
{
//code 
}
```

I'm also getting a file not found error for attach1.css, but that's because I don't have your .css file

*edit*

You're calling document.getElementbyId vs document.getElementById

You really ought to check out the developer tools. they're your friend.

Comment: You may comment out the .css file call in the .html file

Comment: I've edited my answer. Did you run this through the developer console (F12 in chrome)

Comment: Also, you're calling getELementById vs getElementById

Comment: Thanks, that was the mistake - getELementById vs getElementById!!

Comment: glad to have helped! Chrome really will help you though; you can set it to break on errors to avoid common problems like this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the functions in attach1.js by either putting another  tag in your html, or by calling it using a button, like this:
`<button type='button' onclick="play function()">Play</button>`
Just replace "play function" with the name of the function that you have to play stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your code, remove the semi-column from this line

```
function clicker(e);
```

It would be a good idea to look at the errors in the js console

Comment: That's true but it wouldn't stop everything up to that error being parsed.

Comment: Corrected the ; - no change, .js still not called!